# Get destination port in WSPSend

Tags: windows, visual-c++, networking, winsock, winsock-lsp

I am having a problem in getting the destination port number in the WSPSend function in the sample LSP provided with Microsoft platform SDK.

Here is the code that I am using. As shown below, the if statement is not entered. I verified this using a debug function.

I am trying to recognize the outgoing HTTP packets inside this function using the destination port 80.

```
int WSPAPI 
WSPSend(
    SOCKET          s,
    LPWSABUF        lpBuffers,
    DWORD           dwBufferCount,
    LPDWORD         lpNumberOfBytesSent,
    DWORD           dwFlags,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,                             
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine,   
    LPWSATHREADID   lpThreadId,                                 
    LPINT           lpErrno                                             
    )
{
    INT                 ret = SOCKET_ERROR;
    SOCK_INFO          *SocketContext = NULL;
    LPWSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS ProviderOverlapped = NULL;

    *lpErrno = NO_ERROR;

    //
    // Find our provider socket corresponding to this one
    //
    SocketContext = FindAndRefSocketContext(s, lpErrno);
    if ( NULL == SocketContext )
    {
        dbgprint( "WSPSend: FindAndRefSocketContext failed!" );
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // My code starts here!!!
    SOCKET app = SocketContext->LayeredSocket;
    struct sockaddr FAR name;
    int FAR namelen;
    getpeername(app, &name, &namelen);
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin =* (const struct sockaddr_in *) (&name);
    if(sin.sin_port == htons(80))
    {
        // This code is not executed after sending HTTP packets!!
    }
 }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has [getpeername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738533%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) worked? Your code needs to check the return code before using the results.

> If no error occurs, getpeername
>   returns zero. Otherwise, a value of
>   SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a
>   specific error code can be retrieved
>   by calling WSAGetLastError.

That aside, you need to specify `namelen` to be the size of your output structure before making this call - that is my bet for what is wrong here, since `namelen` is not initialized.  It's important to read the [WinSock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741416%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) carefully - Windows is riddled with these API usage rules, and you could waste a lot of time if you don't follow them.

> On call, the namelen parameter
>   contains the size, in bytes, of the
>   name buffer. On return, the namelen
>   parameter contains the actual size, in
>   bytes, of the name parameter returned.

Comment: I checked the return value of the getpeername. It did not return 0!

Comment: @Khaled - that's useful info - set `namelen` to be `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` and this should work better.